# boost::split_regex() не компилируется программа

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost, split

Пытаюсь скомпилировать код ниже командой `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -lboost_regex` на Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Версия буста: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1.

В ответ получаю ошибку, которую я вставил полностью под кодом.

Ключевые слова, которые я искал, чтобы найти решение - "undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher".

С регэкспами бустовскими уже работал и с `boost.asio`. Библиотека ведет себя корректно в этих случаях. Может, я что-то должен доустановить?

P.S. Возможно, вы могли бы подсказать более подходящий способ сделать split строки (пытаюсь распарсить заголовок HTTP, чтобы потом оформить соответствующий ответ).

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void print( vector <string> & v )
{
  for (size_t n = 0; n < v.size(); n++)
    cout << "\"" << v[ n ] << "\"\n";
  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  string s = "one->two->thirty-four";
  vector <string> fields;

  split_regex( fields, s, regex( "->" ) );
  print( fields );

  return 0;
}
```

> /tmp/ccoOSMOs.o: In function `bool boost::regex_search<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)':
>   main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12regex_searchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISB_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SJ_RNS_13match_resultsISJ_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESJ_[_ZN5boost12regex_searchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISB_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SJ_RNS_13match_resultsISJ_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESJ_]+0xba): undefined reference to`boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find()'
>   /tmp/ccoOSMOs.o: In function `boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)':
>   main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10610012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC2ESC_SC_RNS_13match_resultsISC_SF_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSJ_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESC_[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10610012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC5ESC_SC_RNS_13match_resultsISC_SF_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSJ_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESC_]+0x116): undefined reference to`boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >, boost::regex_traits > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: Конечно в академических целях это может быть и полезно, но на практике - возьмите тот же libcurl, он отполирован до нельзя, включая всякие уязвимости, и дополнительные плюшки типа редиректов и т.п.

Comment: Может, Вы могли бы подсказать функцию для этой цели? Не совсем понимаю эту библиотеку. У меня есть сервер, куда приходит запрос. Я его помещаю в строковою переменную и хочу распарсить, но эта библиотека, видимо, работает как-то по-другому. Я не нашел подходящей для этой цели функции.